# How to disable auto-depend on the project but not the only jar when using maven in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management, pom.xml

I am using Maven in Intellij IDEA 11.1.2, and i am working on two different projects and one of them depends on the other one.

Project A's pom.xml as following

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>project.b</groupId>
        <artifactId>project.b</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then IntellIj IDEA will automaticly depend on project B. Sometimes i can compile project A useing mvn command line, but the IDEA shows there are many errors in the source code, and the only way to fix this is removing the project b from the local file systems then removing it from the IDEA.

So i want to diable IDEA to auto-depend on the project but only the jar and do what the pom.xml tells it to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SNAPSHOT dependencies are resolved via project source location, not jar, if you want to depend on the jar instead of the project sources in IDEA, use some real version and install the jar into repository.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, thanks for your reply.  I have the SNAPSHOT version jar installed in the local repository and i am just wondering if this can be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CrazyCoder said,

> SNAPSHOT dependencies are resolved via project source location

I just accept the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should tune [dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Try specifying the scope as `runtime` - *"This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath."*