# intellij multi module project adds module as dependency instead of it's jar

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have 2 maven projects A and B.
B has a maven compile time dependency on A's fat jar.

While importing B as a maven project, A gets added as Module dependency instead of target jar.

Is there a way to disable this?

**B's pom.xml (dependency part)**

`<dependency>
  <groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
</dependency>`

**A's pom.xml (artifact details):**

`<groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
 <artifactId>A</artifactId>
 <version>trunk-SNAPSHOT</version>`

A is packaged to give Fat jar and B is using version plugin to determine A's version.

**Problem:**

These two are modules in Intellij project. Whichever the way I import them, Project B's dependencies list shows project A as module dependency, instead of the SNAPSHOT(or particular version) of project A's jar.

Because of this, whenever I try to package/install on Project B, I am seeing ClassNotFound for some of the helper classes from A.

**Compile log for Project B:**

```
Error:(21, 40) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ImmutableMap
location: package org.xxx.yyy.zzz

Error:(22, 40) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ImmutableSet
location: package org.xxx.yyy.zzz
```

This same class file can be seen in A's SNAPSHOT jar.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? You may publish your pom.xml

Comment: Updated question with pom.xml extracts.

Comment: Where? there is no change in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on a different post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11545441/639107

> SNAPSHOT dependencies are resolved via project source location

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
 <artifactId>A</artifactId>
 <version>trunk-SNAPSHOT<version>
</dependency>
```

Can you try so by adding version to the B´ pom.xml and then, `mvn clean install`

Comment: Tried as suggested. I have updated pom.xml, removed the module and re-imported. After import, again Project A is being shown as module dependency and `mvn clean install` resulted in error (as compilation is considering module code instead of the Jar file)

Comment: You should go to project A´s pom.xml path and you should run "mvn clean install" there and then, you should go to project B´s pom.xml path and make the same there. If it gives the same error, could you provide this error also?

Comment: From command line it works fine, before and after change. The error is ClassNotFound through IntelliJ. This is only for Project B.

Comment: ClassNotFound -> which class ?  It is always better if you copy the whole log and past it here. The other people can see from a better perspective.

Comment: Sorry about that. Update question with suggested details. ImmutableSet is a class file that can be seen in A's SNAPSHOT jar. But is not available for B during compilation since A was added as a Module dependency.

Comment: The package name in the error is "org.xxx.yyy.zzz" but the package of the Project A is com.xxx.yyy. I think it may be the problem.